# How do i set django settings to 12 hour time

Tags: python, django

I am trying to modify settings.py to change the display to 12 hour time using `TIME_INPUT_FORMATS` however it displays it incorrectly when i apply `%P`.

[Docs on it are here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: > "incorrectly"

how? give expected & obtained results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `%I`.

Check out the [Django settings docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TIME_INPUT_FORMATS) which reference the [Python datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)